# Twitter data extraction - json dump for tweets from a user's timeline

Tags: json, image, python-2.7, twitter, tweepy

I am trying to write a python code which extracts tweets for a given user id from his timeline but I also need to save the images attached to tweets which I am unable to. I am using tweepy API, I also tried to extract the json dump for tweets from users timeline. I could only find twitter streaming API able to extract the json dump from streaming tweets.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this small project: https://github.com/geduldig/TwitterGeoPics

It has a command line Python2.X (not 3.X) program that searches for word(s) and downloads any embedded images. It can also do the same by filtering a twitter stream.

You run it like this:

```
python -u -m TwitterGeoPics.StreamNewTweets -words pizza -photo_dir pics
```

The project uses [TwitterAPI](https://github.com/geduldig/TwitterAPI).